# x509: cert signed by unknown authority (possibly bcz of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority cert "kubernetes")

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, x509certificate

I am facing this error when I try any kubectl command, on alternate basis, i.e.,
once the command gives correct output and other time it shows the above error.

```
[root@ip-10-0-3-103 ec2-user]# kubectl get ns
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")

[root@ip-10-0-3-103 ec2-user]# kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   4d1h
kube-node-lease   Active   4d1h
kube-public       Active   4d1h
kube-system       Active   4d1h
migration         Active   3d19h
[root@ip-10-0-3-103 ec2-user]#
```

This is the issue, the same command is behaving two way.
I did refer the answers on StackOverflow itself, but did not work:

> ```
> $ sudo kubeadm reset
> $ sudo swapoff -a 
>
> $ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.10.0/16 --kubernetes- 
>   version "1.18.3"
> $ sudo rm -rf $HOME/.kube
>
> $ mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
> $ sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
> $ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
>
> $ sudo systemctl enable docker.service
> $ sudo service kubelet restart
>
> $ kubectl get nodes
> ```

Comment: Sounds like you may have multiple endpoints on the load balancer and some have a real public cert, others have internal self-signed?